# In what sense is $\Bbb R(x)$ an "instantiation" of the hyperreals?

Tags: polynomials, terminology, real-numbers, nonstandard-analysis, nonarchimedian-analysis

*I'm teaching myself about hyperreal numbers. My main motivation for doing so is that they include infinite numbers, whose existence I hear disputed & doubted often as "quantifying the unquantifiable".*

---

In [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/dvyVPA1GTyA), around twelve minutes in, it states that

$$\Bbb R(x)=\left\{ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\,\middle|\, f(x), g(x)\in \Bbb R[x], g(x)\neq 0\right\},$$

where $\Bbb R[x]$ is the set of polynomials in $x$ with real coefficients, is an *instantiation* of the hyperreal numbers ${}^*\Bbb R$.

> What is meant by "instantiation" here?

Please note that hyperreal numbers are not rigorously defined in the video.

---

I have only a rudimentary understanding of hyperreal numbers; I'm not sure about what they are exactly. Perhaps that is where my confusion lies.

The [Wikipedia article on hyperreals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number) doesn't contain a definition either.

For questions on what hyperreals are,  see the following:

- [What are hyperreal numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/967115/104041)
- [What are hyperreal numbers? (Clarifying an already answered question)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2135263/104041)

Their answers make sense but I wouldn't say I have a firm grasp of them.

---

I'm given to understand that hyperreals are of use to model theory. That might explain where the terminology in question comes from. However, I don't remember where I heard this claim. (I *think* it was in a Numberphile video.)

---

*A suspicion:* I think $\Bbb R(x)$ is to ${}^*\Bbb R$ what the quotient $\Bbb R[x]/(x^2+1)$ is to $\Bbb C$.

Please help :)

Comment: it doesn't mean much; in the last part of the video he picked an infinite $x\in{}^*\Bbb R$ which then gives you $\Bbb R(x)\subset{}^*\Bbb R$, and he briefly mentioned how to compare (the sizes of) two elements of $\Bbb R(x)$ (by expanding them to a Laurent series in $x^{-1}$).

Comment: The creator of the video seems to not understand what hyperreal numbers actually are.  I would not recommend it as anything more than a very loose layman's introduction to some of the ideas involved.

Comment: $\mathbb R(x)$ with the order defined in video is a model for the axiom $A,B$ and $C$ in part 1A of  [Keisler 2007](https://people.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/foundations.pdf), but not the axioms from part 1C. It is not a field of hyperreal numbers.

Comment: "Instantiation" (or "An instance") is computer science jargon for what in mathematical logic jargon is a "model". See more on mathematical logic in Ebbinghaus, Flum, Thomas, for elementary logic. Particularly Chap VI.4.

Comment: @p.co Unfortunately, this does not actually model the hyperreals.

Comment: Numberphile is full of junk. Please don't refer to them if you want to learn proper mathematics!

Comment: "[The Hyperreal number system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1305176/the-hyperreal-number-system)" has a reasonably good gloss of what "hyperreals" mean, which is consistent with the wikipedia article, and of course contrary to your quoted video.

Comment: No, @user21820, as it doesn't discuss $\Bbb R(x)$.

Comment: @Shaun: It doesn't have to discuss it; it **mathematically** forbids it; as it is **not** an elementarily equivalent structure!

Comment: Come on, now, @user21820; there must be *some* sense in which the concepts are related - that's what I'm interested in. I invite you to answer this question.

Comment: I do not understand why you believe that the video you cited is correct. Just ask any other model theorist if you don't believe what I and Alex Kruckman said already here and at the linked thread...

Comment: A useful discussion of some of the ideas involved in hyperreal numbers can be found [here (in a chat room)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61190100#61190100).

Comment: "there must be some sense in which the concepts are related - that's what I'm interested in." Why must there be, exactly?

Comment: You may find helpful [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/63996/242) (and its links to expositions on this and related topics).

Comment: I have no idea how related this actually is, but Terry Tao proposed a "cheap non-standard analysis" that doesn't use ultrafilters [in this blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/a-cheap-version-of-nonstandard-analysis/).

Comment: @CalvinKhor The method Tao describes (using  a Frechet filter) is very old  - see the citations I give on Schmieden and Laugwitz's approach [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/63996/242) (link in my prior comment) for its many disadvantages vs. a free ultrafilter (update: this is also mentioned in the comments on Tao's blog post - so see there too).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The claim in the video you link to is incorrect; to be honest, no video making such a claim should be used as a reference for technical topics. There is **no substantive sense** in which $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is related to hyperreals.

The most that can be said is that $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is an ordered (well, fine, order*able*) field with infinitesimal elements - that is, a **non-Archimedean field**. Hyperreal fields, however, are *much more* than merely non-Archimedean fields. A hyperreal field must have a "high degree of similarity" to $\mathbb{R}$ itself, in a particular technical sense. $\mathbb{R}(x)$ demonstrably lacks this, most obviously since it does not satisfy the property "$\forall u\ge 0\exists v(v^2=u)$." So we don't even have $\mathbb{R}(x)\equiv\mathbb{R}$, let alone that $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is a hyperreal field *(see below)*!

To someone new to the subject of nonstandard analysis, this may feel like uncharitable hair-splitting. I want to emphasize as strongly as possible that the difference between mere non-Archimedeanness and hyperrealness is *huge*. Remember that the whole point of hyperrealness is that a hyperreal field should let you "transfer" results to the standard real numbers $\mathbb{R}$, so that infinitesimal *methods* can still provide real *results*. The fact that this is possible at all is really neat and awesome, and ignoring precisely what makes hyperrealness special in the interest of a superficial gain in accessibility is a pedagogical disservice.

---

It may help at this point to see the (most common in my experience) precise definition of hyperreal-ness, in order to contrast it with $\mathbb{R}(x)$. Let $\Sigma$ be the expansion of the language of fields by a symbol for every finite-arity relation on the reals, and let $\mathcal{R}$ be the reals construed as a $\Sigma$-structure in the obvious way. A **hyperreal field** is then just a proper elementary extension $\mathcal{F}$ of $\mathcal{R}$.

Note that strictly speaking a "hyperreal field" isn't a field but rather an *expansion of* a field (compare $\mathcal{R}$ with the much-less-complicated $(\mathbb{R};+,\times,0,1)$. This is a bit messy, so we describe $\mathcal{F}$ as a field equipped with a *third-order* operation ${}^*$ which assigns to each finite-arity relation $A$ on $\mathbb{R}$ an extension $^*A$ on the underlying set of $F$ which satisfies some simple properties. This amounts to the same thing as the above, but is arguably more convenient in two significant ways: pdagogically this approach is more accessible to non-logicians, and technically it lets us pay more careful attention to exactly how much transfer is needed for a given application.

Comment: For further elaboration on the points above see the papers I cite [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/63996/242), which includes highly accessible *Monthly* expositions, as well as pertinent historical remarks from Dauben's biography of Abby Robinson.